# Is there a very efficient way to delete from a SQLite table records not in another SQLite table?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables: Phrase and PhraseSource. Both have an identical structure but it's possible that PhraseSource might have less rows sometimes when I download data into it.  I don't want to change the contents of Phrase but I would like to delete those rows that no longer exist. Here is what I am using and it works:

```
DELETE FROM Phrase WHERE PhraseId NOT IN (SELECT PhraseId FROM PhraseSource)
```

However there are a large number of rows in both these tables. Is there a more efficient way I can do the delete?

Comment: Do you have a complaint with the current performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometime i believes on `NOT EXISTS` :

```
DELETE 
FROM Phrase
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM PhraseSource PS WHERE PS.PhraseId = Phrase.PhraseId);
```

Answer (score 1):

Deleting lots of rows can be expensive.  I would start with writing this as `exists`:

```
DELETE FROM Phrase
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 PhraseSource ps WHERE phrase.PhraseId = ps.PhraseId);
```

This can take care of an index on `PhraseSource(PhraseId)`.  That is probably sufficient.

If not, it may be the overhead of the deletes that is your real issue.  To get around that, you would need to use a temporary table.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by batches, have an executor service and submit the query to it with several threads, and the query will become smth like this

```
DELETE FROM Phrase WHERE PhraseId NOT IN (SELECT PhraseId FROM PhraseSource limit batchSize offset nextBatchIndex)
```

Where batchsize and nextBatchIndex are parameters you can play with to get the optimization you want